# Postgresql: add to CASE

Tags: postgresql, case

I have this code in Postgresql:

```
CASE 
    WHEN a > b THEN 'a is bigger than b'
    WHEN a > c THEN 'a is bigger than c'
    ELSE ' '
END AS "all bigs",
```

Now the thing is I need to add both WHEN's combined, so that second WHEN does
not erase first one.

My column should look as (`a is bigger than b\na is bigger than c`):

```
all bigs
---------
a is bigger than a
a is bigger than c
```

not like:

```
all bigs
---------
a is bigger than c
```

How to do this?

@zedfoxus, trying this, but no luck ("ERROR:  syntax error at or near "UNION""):

```
CASE 
    WHEN a > b THEN 'a is bigger than b'::text
UNION ALL
    WHEN a > c THEN 'a is bigger than c'::text
END AS "all bigs"
```

Comment: The `CASE` statement only resolves a value for a single row.  It can't just magically add more rows to your query.  You'll need to show your *entire* query and tell us what you're trying to do, preferably with examples of the dataset you're querying against.

Comment: @MikeChristensen, why would you need the whole query? This should be enough I think. Seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: Is this the only column you're returning, or are there others?  What's the desired result if `a` is the smallest value?  One blank row?  Two blank rows?

Comment: @MikeChristensen, if only a, then just one row in a cell, same if b. If a AND b, then both in one row (cell).

Comment: Ah, so you want a result of `a is bigger than b\na is bigger than c` in a single cell?  You *don't* want multiple rows?

Comment: @MikeChristensen, no Mike. Just in one cell. Just like you've shown here.

Comment: Ok cool.  I'd just add this as the first case: `WHEN a > b and a > c THEN 'a is bigger than b\na is bigger than c'`

Comment: @MikeChristensen, if it was that easy... I need to do it for many options, not two as I have shown here in question. :)

Comment: I've given up on you.  If you're not interested in explaining your entire problem, then there's nothing we can do to help.  At this point you understand your problem better than any of us do, so you're the best person to figure out a solution.  Best of luck!

Comment: @MikeChristensen, sorry, didn't want to disappoint you. I am just telling that I have shown here 2 options, a>b and a>c. Now the thing is that there are many possible options in terms of a, b, c, d... until k. As you see, I can't create the code for all of them. How many would there be then, if I apply this code to all, 100? 500? 1000? That's why I am looking for simpler solution in a few lines, may be using UNION as zedfoxus suggested. That's it.

Comment: Hmm, yea I can't think of a super simple solution to that problem.  You might end up having to write your own custom function that builds the exact string you want.  Perhaps someone else has a better answer.

Comment: @MikeChristensen, I will figure out. For now I am creating 11 columns, then I will CONCAT in the end. Seems like this is the only simple solution.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help!

Comment: That's probably a better solution.  Don't do too much logic in SQL.  You'll just frustrate yourself.  Just get the raw data you need, and process it with a real programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
create table test (a int, b int, c int);
insert into test values (3, 2, 1);

select case when a > b then 'a is bigger than b' else '' end as "all bigs" from test
union all
select case when a > c then 'a is bigger than c' else '' end as "all bigs" from test
```

Comment: could FROM 'test' be removed? This is just a view in db.

Comment: Possibly. Can you put your `create view` statement in your question so that I can provide better guidance?

Comment: This will also result in 2 *blank* rows even if `a` is smaller than `b` and `c`, and 1 blank row if `a` is smaller than only one other value.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. We'll just have to wait to find out how the view OP is talking about looks like. We can make the `select..union...` a subquery and then eliminate any blank rows.

Comment: Agreed.  This is probably the best answer based on the very limited information we were given.